# Is "how to say" incorrect?

Tags: word-usage, questions

I am confused by this [video](http://xue.youdao.com/sw/m/1038568?from=groupmessage&isappinstalled=0), in which the speaker claims usages like **'How to say egg in Chinese'** is incorrect, and **'How do you say egg in Chinese'** is correct. Is it right?

Comment: It's "How do you say 'egg' in English?"

Comment: Question belongs on http://ell.stackexchange.com -- Q&A for speakers of other languages learning English

Comment: There's something a bit odd about the reasoning implicit in the statement "How to [or _do you_] say [some English word] in English?"

Comment: The problem is idioms. "How do you say" is an idiom. "How do I say" is an idiom. "How to say" is an idiom but only for non-native English speakers, particularly Chinese. English is particular in demanding a subject for every sentence. This trips up some non-native speakers. So much so that "How to say" is seen as a stereotypical mistake, even when it's grammatically correct.

Comment: Here is a correct exchange followed by a wrong one. Right: Hank: "How do you say 'egg' in Chinese?" Chi: "Hi, Hank! This is how to say 'egg' in Chinese: [insert Chinese speak]" ---- Wrong: Hank: "How to say 'egg' in Chinese?" Chi: "Hi, Hank! This is how do you say 'egg' in Chinese: [insert Chinese speak]"